# Use system properties in <entity> in data-config.xml

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm trying to use system properties in my entity in the data-config.xml file, but they don't get resolved to their set value.

I have specified it as this:

```
<entity name="e"
        processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
        url="/documents?a={my.system.property}">
```

But it tries to access the url as it says above: ".../documents?a={my.system.property}".
In the same data-config,xml file, I'm able to use system properties in the datasource field though:

```
<dataSource name="ds"
            url="${my.base.url}" />
```

So the properties are obviously being set the correct way. But why can't I have them in entity?